# remove accents or tilde from a string in python

Tags: python, character-encoding

I have the following example string to make a function which will remove accents 
is an email header and I store it in the bd but since I get the header I get it that way

```
 ('Cotización pruebá ácentos')
    string = m['subject']

self.remove_accents(string.decode('utf-8'))
```

the function that I have is the following

```
def remove_accents(self, s):
    return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if 
             unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')
```

it removes the accents but it returns something like this

```
=?utf-8?b?q290axphy2nds24=?= =?utf-8?b?ihbydwviw6e
```

how do I decode the chain

Comment: `=?utf-8?b?q290axphy2nds24=?= =?utf-8?b?ihbydwviw6e` is encoded word encoding, used for encoding email headers.  Your code does not produce this result using the string you provided.  Please edit your question to provide an [mcve]

Comment: It is an email header and I store it in the bd but since I get the header I get it that way =?utf-8?b?q290axphy2nds24=?= =?utf-8?b?ihbydwviw6e

Comment: Try :   `from email.header import decode_header

_subject = decode_header(m['subject'])   _subject = self.remove_accents(_subject.decode('utf-8')) `